# How do I only send response.data to my controllers instead of the entire response when using $http.jsonp?

Tags: angularjs

I have a resolve that makes a webapi call in order to pass data to various controllers. But it always sends the complete response with HTTP headers/etc to the controllers instead of just the data. So my controllers have to access the data like this:

`response.data.myObj1` and `response.data.myObj2`

I just want `data.myObj1` and `data.myObj2`.

Right now my resolve looks like this:

```
resolve: {
          eventData: function ($stateParams, $http) {
               return $http.jsonp('http://localhost:10569/api/eventView/1?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
               }
            }
```

But I've also tried this:

```
resolve: {
                eventData: function ($stateParams, $http) {
                    $http.jsonp('http://localhost:10569/api/eventView/1?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
        return data;
      });
                }
            }
```

and this:

```
resolve: {
                eventData: function ($stateParams, $http) {
                    $http.jsonp('http://localhost:10569/api/eventView/1?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      });
                }
            }
```

The last two give me undefined errors when I try to access any of the objects on the data object sent to the controllers (eventData).

Comment: Why did you remove `return $http` in the second two examples?!

Comment: Because I'm trying to return only the data, not the entire response.

Comment: right, but you can't return from inside a callback, so you must return $http. your .then and .success would modify what your outside methods can access from the promise.

Comment: Your question basically reads "why do my second two examples return `undefined` when i don't return anything from them?"

Comment: If the return is tied to $http, how do I tell it I only want it to send through the data object of the response as 'eventData' when injected into my controllers?

Comment: How do you think it worked before? $http.jsonp doesn't return the data you're getting, it returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` returns promises. That's what all of the `.then`, `.catch` syntax is.

Its what allows you to run code when a promise resolves and what facilitates the chain-ability.

You manipulate the data running through that promise chain, so inside each `.then()` when a promise resolves. This means a promise can be created and returned, `.then`'s can be attached to it but it won't be 'activated' untill it resolves. In your case the AJAX returns. Once its resolved it runs all your `.then`'s sending the data from one to the next in a chain allowing you to act upon it.

So to answer your question, you would intercept your promise chain before it exits the service and manipulate the data before it gets back to your controller.

So pretty much exactly like your last code snippet except for one bit, the extra return before `$http`.

```
resolve: {
  eventData: function($stateParams, $http) {
    return $http.jsonp('http://localhost:10569/api/eventView/1?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

That return is very important, your not returning your whole response object at that point as your AJAX request will not have resolved by then. what you are doing is returning a promise object with your chained `.then()`.

When the AJAX returns it will resolve the promise and run your `.then()` reducing your response object and sending that out to your calling code, in this case the controller.

Hope that helps explain whats happening.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!